# Does loopback provide indexing of DB as part of meta data?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I just want to know if we can define which columns to be indexed as part of model definition and loopback automatically creates them as part of auto migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify indexes in the model definition file

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Indexes